# About an error with foldl1 (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, fold

I have a data type that goes:

```
BinHeap a = [BinTree a]

BinTree a = Node a i (BinHeap a)
```

I want a function to go through a Bintree a and give me the smallest a.

```
extractMin :: BinHeap a -> a
extractMin ps
 = foldl1 (\(Node x y z) (Node x' y' z') -> Node (smaller x x') y z) ps
 where
  smaller x y = if x <= y then x else y
```

And it crashed. And i do not know why. Because the function within fold1 outputs a BinTree, therefore it should not crash.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you explain what "and it crashed" means?  Did you get a specific error message?  Does it work for some inputs but not others?  etc.

Comment: `foldl1` requires the input list is non-empty, so if the heap is empty you will get an exception.

Comment: do you have `type BinHeap a = [BinTree a]` or just `BinHeap a = [BinTree a]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data type says `BinTree` which seems to imply 'binary tree' but it isn't defined as a binary tree. It isn't even valid syntax, so I'm not quite sure what your data type is (is `BinHeap` a `type` or `data`? Why are there two datatypes, instead of one datatype and 2 constructors?)

If you use `foldl1` on a list of `BinTree a` then your output will be `BinTree a`, not `a`. The correct type signature is `extractMin :: Ord a => BinHeap a -> BinTree a` .

The function `smaller` already exists, it is called `min`.

The most idiomatic way is probably to use `Data.Foldable` which will automatically give you `minimum` for a `Foldable` instance.

```
import Data.Foldable
import Prelude hiding (minimum)
import Data.Monoid

data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a] | Leaf

instance Foldable Tree where
    -- foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Tree a -> m
    foldMap _ Leaf = mempty
    foldMap f (Tree a xs) = f a `mappend` mconcat (map (foldMap f) xs)

minTree :: Ord a => Tree a -> a
minTree = minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what is wrong with your code, but I can see two possibilities:

- The type parameter (a) does not have a constraint that it implement `Ord`.  Therefore, you cannot compare them in the smaller function.
- The lambda expression that you are passing to foldl1 should be in parentheses.  Otherwise, the compiler understands that it runs to the end of the line.